# How does the var x and var lineY code work?

Tags: javascript

I have this processing.js code made on khan academy:

```
background(255, 255, 247);
stroke(173, 222, 237);

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    
    var lineY = 20 + (i * 20);
    line(0, lineY, 400, lineY);
    
}

for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    
    var x = 20 + (j * 20);
    line(x, 0, x, 400);

}
```

What does the

```
var lineY = 20 + (i * 20);
```

code do? And what does the

```
var x = 20 + (j * 20);
```

code do?

Im a beginner

Comment: Please read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). This is basic JS syntax. Stack Overflow doesn’t replace a [JS tutorial](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/4642212).

Comment: What's unclear about that simple expression?

Answer (score 0):

Each one declares (tells javascript to create) a variable (a word), and initializes the value (sets the initial value) to whatever is on the other side of the `=` sign.

```js
var lineY = 20 + (i * 20);
line(0, lineY, 400, lineY);
```

is equivalent to

```js
line(0, 20 + (i * 20), 400, 20 + (i * 20));
```

however, using a variable makes it so you don't have to do the same calculation again (and makes code more readable).

Answer (score 0):

`var lineY = 20 + (i * 20);`

This means that the variable called `lineY` will be equal to 20 plus the value of `i` times 20. So if `i` is 1, then `lineY` will equal `40`.

The variables `i` and `j` will be values of 20 or less, based on the maximum value in the `for` loop.